# Limit Probability Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Show that $\lim_{\lambda\to \infty}$ $P(|X+3Y-4 \lambda| \geq \lambda) = 0$ where $X$ and $Y$ are poisson random variables with $X$ ~ $Poi_ \lambda$ and $Y$ ~ $Poi_ \lambda$

Comment: Can you edit the question, regarding the limit, what have you tried?

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent Done

Comment: Thanks and what have you done? Hint: What can you say about the distribution of the sum of $X$ and $Y$, what would be a good inequality that gives a sufficient estimate?

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent That $X+Y$ ~ $Poi_{2\lambda}$?

Comment: That is correct! Observe that however that $3Y$ is indeed not Poisson (why?), how can you find a suitable upper bond that asymptotically goes to zero as $\lambda \to \infty$.

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent I am confused on this part. Is it using Chebychev's inequality ?

Comment: Yes correct, to what random variable are you applying this inequality?

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent Is it $X+Y$? I am not too sure. This is the part I am stuck with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there: The main observation is that $\mathbb E[X+3Y] = \mathbb E[X] + 3 \mathbb E[Y] = 4\lambda$, since $X$ and $Y$ are both Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda > 0$. But this is enough take $Z = X+3Y$ then
$$
\mathbb E[|X+3Y-4\lambda| \geq \lambda] = \mathbb E[|Z-\mathbb E[Z]| \geq \lambda] \leq \frac{\text{Var}(X)+9\text{Var}(Y)+6\text{Cov}(X,Y)}{\lambda^2},
$$
where we used Chebyshev's inequality. But now since $\text{Var}(X) = \lambda$ and $\text{Var}(Y) = \lambda$ and $\text{Cov}(X,Y) \leq \sqrt{\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y)} = \lambda$ using Cauchy Schwarz. Now everything boils down to
$$
\mathbb E[|X+3Y-4\lambda| \geq \lambda] \leq C \frac{1}{\lambda} \to 0 \quad \text{ as }\lambda \to \infty,
$$
and this finishes the proof.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it. The last bit I haven't covered yet but I understand everything prior to that. Thanks again

Comment: Which piece did you not understand?